# Markings in Second Waltz by Dimitri Shostakovich

Tags: piano, notation

I came across these indications in a piano piece: the Second Waltz by Dimitri Shostakovich.

[image: 1. 3. x p, 2. x f]

What do "1.3. x ***p***" and "2. x ***f***" mean?

Answer (score 16):

That means on the first and third repeats, play piano (quietly), on the second repeat, play forte (loudly).

Comment: Yup, it seems like an attempt a rendering at the piano the different orchestration of the different repeats in the original orchestral version (if I'm not mistaken, solo oboe - first time, full violin section - 1st repeat, solo trombone (but rather smoohtly) - repetition after B part.